# RadListView: Unknown custom element: <ReorderHandle>

Tags: nativescript-vue, radlistview, nativescript-ui-listview

I am getting an error while using `ReorderHandle` in `reorderMode="Drag"` in `RadListView` component of `nativescript-ui-listview/vue` like

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ReorderHandle> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

How can I use ReorderHandle in `Nativescript-vue` according to this [doc link](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/item-reorder#defining-a-reorder-handle)?

Any help on this functionality will be appreciated.

Here are my codes

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import RadListView from 'nativescript-ui-listview/vue';
Vue.use(RadListView);
```

**My Vue Component**

```
<RadListView ref="listView" for="(manager, index) in managers" :itemReorder="true" reorderMode="Drag">
    <v-template>
        <Label>{{ manager.name }}</Label>
        <ReorderHandle col="1" verticalAlignment="center">
            <Image android:src="res://reorder_icon" ios:src="res://reorder-icon" stretch="none" verticalAlignment="stretch" margin="16" />
        </ReorderHandle>
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Vue example](https://github.com/msaelices/ns-ui-vue-demo) of that.

Like you can see in the code you don't need to add `<ReorderHandle>`

Example:

```
<template>
  <RadListView ref="listView"
               for="item in items"
               pullToRefresh="true"
               itemReorder="true"
               swipeActions="true"
               @itemTap="onItemTap"
               @pullToRefreshInitiated="onPullToRefreshInitiated"
               @itemReordered="onItemReordered"
               @itemSwipeProgressStarted="onSwipeStarted">
    <v-template>
      <GridLayout columns="50, *" rows="*" class="item">
        <Image :src="item.image" col="0" class="thumbnail" />
        <StackLayout col="1">
          <label :text="item.name" class="h2" col="1"/>
          <label :text="item.description" class="p" col="1"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </v-template>

    <v-template name="itemswipe">
      <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto" backgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout id="mark-view" col="0" class="swipe-item left"
                     orientation="horizontal" @tap="onLeftSwipeClick">
          <Label text="mark" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout id="delete-view" col="2" class="swipe-item right"
                     orientation="horizontal" @tap="onRightSwipeClick">
          <Label text="delete" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" />
        </StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
  </RadListView>
</template>
```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/msaelices/ns-ui-vue-demo/blob/master/app/components/ItemList.vue).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to implement functionality where I can define handle for reorder functionality in reorderMode="Drag" because currently, I can drag from the whole item instead of just drag handle. Is there a way to implement such functionality? Actually, Drag mode creating an issue in vertical scrolling too. so, for now, I have added HoldAndDrag mode.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with this: `because currently, I can drag from the whole item instead of just drag handle`. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Drag or reorder handle means I can define some portion or specific area from where only I can drag item. In doc link which I posted in question, you can see an image where 3 bar icon is shown which is drag handle for re-ordering items

Comment: I understand now what you mean. The answer I posted is the only thing I'm aware of that is possible with nativescript-vue.

Comment: That simple re-ordering I have done already. Anyway thanks for the support.